# How to explain UFW firewall LAN packet from external source on non-forwarded port?

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, ufw

I have a small home server with hostname `mango` running Debian, with UFW firewall and logcheck installed. For years, my (NAT) router has a very limited number of port forwards to this mango server. UPnP is turned OFF at my router (at least, that's what it says).

```
           ┌───────────┐         ┌───────────┐         ┌──────────┐
           │   cable   │     DMZ │  router   │         │  mango   │
INTERNET ──┤   modem   ├─────────┤(NAT+some  ├────┬────┤10.0.0.213│
           │           │         │prt fw'ing)│    │    │(runs UFW)│
           └───────────┘         └───────────┘    │    └──────────┘
                                                  │
                                                  │    ┌──────────┐
                                                  │    │          │
                                                  ├────┤          │
                                                  │    │          │
                                                  │    └──────────┘
                                                 ...
```

Sometimes I get emailed (multiple) logcheck entries like below which I can not understand how they are possible.

```
Mar 29 22:03:45 mango kernel: [690469.612733] [UFW BLOCK] 
IN=eth0 OUT=
MAC=b8:27:eb:66:ca:e1:00:8e:f2:4b:ee:9c:08:00:45:08:00:88:e4:b9:40:00:0c:11:3b:27
SRC=18.195.48.229
DST=10.0.0.213 
LEN=136 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=12 ID=58553 DF PROTO=UDP 
SPT=57673 DPT=51221 LEN=116
```

It reports an external ip (18.195.48.229, geolocated in Germany, not my home country) trying to access mango (10.0.0.213, mac:b8:27:eb:66:ca:e1) on a closed UDP destination port (DPT=51221) which is **NOT** configured or forwarded on my router (and UPnP is turned OFF).  I can see the packet comes from my router (mac: 00:8e:f2:4b:ee:9c)

**Question:**

How can this traffic to a non-forwarded port, reporting an external ip source, end up in my network at this place?
Where should I look to understand what is going on?

**What I already considered**

- One explanation I can think of is that another device in my network is doing ip routing/forwarding.  But, the MAC entry shows the packet came from my router (00:8e:f2:4b:ee:9c), so my assumption does not hold.
- Automatic UPnP port forwaring. But UPnP is turned off in my router.
- Could this be a (NAT-routed) reply from a connection originally originating from my mango host (10.0.0.213)?

Comment: Both are likely ports from the ephemeral port range. It’s UDP. NAT Hole Punching may be in play. Are you running any peer-to-peer software? Note that browsers also use NAT Hole Punching for WebRTC.

Comment: @DanielB: I don't run any peer-to-peer software that I know of. The mango host does run a unifi controller. After reading up a bit on NAT Hole punching, sounds interesting. Would there be a realistic way for me to find out and confirm? (given the connections only happen sporadically)

Comment: Hm the only real chance I see would be to check which program owns the UDP socket at the blocked port at the time the packet is blocked. Certainly doable, but I’m not sure how exactly. // (Apparently, the IP address you see may be “owned” by Twilio.)